# I get error in following php syntax. "You have an error in your SQL syntax;" .

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Create Table Column(
    ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Name VARCHAR(225),
    ProductName VARCHAR(225) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Category VARCHAR(225),
    Company VARCHAR(225),
    Material VARCHAR(225),
    ModelNo VARCHAR(225),
    Size VARCHAR(225),
    Gender VARCHAR(225),
    Price FLOAT NOT NULL,
    Display VARCHAR(225),
    Weight VARCHAR(225),
    Color VARCHAR(225),
    Product-Information MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL  
)
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP, let alone PHP syntax.  As you can see from the error message, your *SQL syntax* is incorrect.

Comment: In this case, it's obvious but generally, it's the next part of the error message that's actually useful to us.

Comment: and your Pk is all wrong

Comment: And it's immensely unlikely that you would want FLOAT for storing DECIMAL values.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this: `Column` is a reserve keyword so put them in `backticks` And also put `Product-Information` in backticks

```
Create Table `Column`(
    ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Name VARCHAR(225),
    ProductName VARCHAR(225) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Category VARCHAR(225),
    Company VARCHAR(225),
    Material VARCHAR(225),
    ModelNo VARCHAR(225),
    Size VARCHAR(225),
    Gender VARCHAR(225),
    Price FLOAT NOT NULL,
    Display VARCHAR(225),
    Weight VARCHAR(225),
    Color VARCHAR(225),
    `Product-Information` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL  
)
```

However this will not work as well since this will result in error saying the error:- *Schema Creation Failed: Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key*, so try this:

```
Create Table `Column`(
    ID INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    Name VARCHAR(225),
    ProductName VARCHAR(225) NOT NULL ,
    Category VARCHAR(225),
    Company VARCHAR(225),
    Material VARCHAR(225),
    ModelNo VARCHAR(225),
    Size VARCHAR(225),
    Gender VARCHAR(225),
    Price FLOAT NOT NULL,
    Display VARCHAR(225),
    Weight VARCHAR(225),
    Color VARCHAR(225),
    `Product-Information` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL  
)
```

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/62616)**

Comment: Those aren't quotes. They are backticks. That's a big difference.

Comment: @spuemaacne:- You may accept this as an answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

The syntax error is near the minus sign in Product-Information remove it and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

**Product-Information** is not correct because of minus sign
change column name, for example use **Product_Information** or **ProductInformation** insted